# using array values in chart.js data and label field

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, chart.js, chart.js2

I wish to pass values of an array to the data and label fields of the chart.js dataset.

Here the code from success of ajax call made to fetch json data. I fetch the json data and store it into an array.

```
Data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
var count = Data.length;
var counter = 0;
while(count > 0) {
    LabelResult[counter] =[Data[counter].TIME];
    counter++;
    count --;
}
```

Now i wish to use this label values into the labels filed.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [LabelResult],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [DataResult],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    }    
});
```

But there seems some issue and the data is not getting rendered on the chart

Comment: values are getting inserted into LabelResult at LabelResult[counter] =[Data[counter].TIME];

Comment: yes this is how they are declared var LabelResult = [];
var DataResult = [];

Comment: it appears as if only one label having all the array valuessuch as a stack piled up.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

LabelResult is an array, change

```
labels: [LabelResult]
```

to

```
labels: LabelResult
```

Also:

```
data: [DataResult]
```

to

```
data: DataResult
```

Like:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: LabelResult,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: DataResult,
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    }    
});
```

Comment: in case of it seem to work but now in case of labels: LabelResult but not in case of  data: DataResult

Answer (score 3):

I think you could try to remove some brackets.

```
while(count > 0){
     LabelResult[counter] = Data[counter].TIME; // here removed brackets
      counter++;
      count --;
}
```

and

```
data: {
    labels: LabelResult, // here removed brackets
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: DataResult, // here removed brackets
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
```

I hope that will works.

Comment: in case of it seem to work but now in case of labels: LabelResult but not in case of  data: DataResult