# ChartJs create Chart from array

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am getting the data and labels for my ChartJs chart via ajax and I create an array out of this.

When I make a console.log, the array looks like it would be working, but the chart has no labels and no data.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869815/using-array-values-in-chart-js-data-and-label-field) question here, but it doesn't solved the problem.

Here is my code for the chartJs:

```
               config = {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: "Aufrufe",
                            data: dataarray,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.8)'
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true,
                        legend: false
                    }
                }
```

and the arrays that I get from console.log:

[image]

That's how I create the array:

```
/* create a labels array */
                        while(year !== (new Date).getFullYear() || month !== enddate) {
                            console.log(year, month);
                            labels.push(month + " " + year);
                            month++;
                            if(month === 13) {
                                year++;
                                month = 1;
                            }

                        }
```

But the chart is simply an empty chart...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the Ajax request was async. So the chart was drawn without any data.

The ajax request has to have `async: false,` so the data can be loaded and after that the chart draws with the data.