# chart.js scatter chart- datasets data in array not showing data

Tags: chart.js

I'm super begginer in js, would like to populate data section of scatter chart with previously defined array (recentEventsCounter1).

Below does not work:

`var recentEventsCounter1 = [{ x: -10, y: 0 },{ x: 0, y: 10 }];
[...]
data: [recentEventsCounter1]`

This work with no problems:
`data: [{ x: -10, y: 0 },{ x: 0, y: 10 }]`

entire code:

```
    var recentEventsCounter1 = [{ x: -10, y: 0 },{ x: 0, y: 10 }]; 
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Scatter Dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'Green',
            borderColor: 'Green',
            borderDash: [1,2,3,4],
            borderDashOffset: 10,
            showLines: false,
            spanGap: true, 
            borderStyleCap: "butt", 
            fill: false, 
            steppedline: true ,
           borderWidth: 10,
            pointBackgroundColor: ['yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'indigo'],
            data: [
              //{ x: -10, y: 0 },{ x: 0, y: 10 } or recentEventsCounter1 ?
            ]
        }]
    },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using array values in chart.js data and label field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869815/using-array-values-in-chart-js-data-and-label-field)

Comment: your code doesn't show up

Comment: thanks @tata.leona this works for me